# Criar uma Sequence, através de uma trigger. Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

Estou tentando criar uma `sequence` em uma `trigger`.

Ao tentar criar por `Execute Immediate`, estou tendo o seguinte retorno:

> ORA: 4092 - Cannot commit in a trigger.

Por tudo que já pesquisei, usar o `Execute Immediate` em uma trigger não é possível, pois ele está em uma `dll` que emite um `commit` automático.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra forma de criar uma sequence por uma trigger.

Segue o código da trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_TEST"  
  AFTER UPDATE ON TEST_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ01' ||
                       '      MINVALUE 1' ||
                       '      MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999' ||
                       '      START WITH 1' ||
                       '      INCREMENT BY 1' ||
                       '      NOCACHE';      
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20200, 'Error');
   END;  
END
```

Comment: Inclua o código de sua tentativa

Comment: Editei e inseri o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um Trigger não deve criar um objeto. Cada vez que ele for disparado, tentará criar o objeto novamente...
Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer incrementar a sequência SEQ01 após a update da tabela TEST_TABLE. Certo?
Se for isso, dentro do execute immediate deve conter:

select SEQ01.nextval from dual;

Desde tenha criado a sequence anteriormente.

Comment: Na verdade, existira uma validação olhando o nome da sequence para ver se ela já existe, caso não exista, será criada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar a sequencia em uma procedure e chamar a procedure dentro da sua trigger assim será possível criar ou utilizar a sequencia.

De uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016510/creating-and-using-sequence-in-oracle-stored-procedure-sequence-doesnt-exist

Mas acredito que a melhor prática seria criar a sequencia normal tendo em vista que você já sabe que ela deverá existir.

Comment: Então Uerlen, eu tentei fazer isso, joguei a criação da sequencia em uma procedure e chamei ela na trigger, porem retorna o mesmo erro.